# Integrating over an ElementMarker area in FEM

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I'd like to know if there is a way to integrate an interpolating function obtained by solving a PDE in the FEM framework over a region with an ElementMarker assigned to it? I'm not sure if I'm clear so I'll write a small example.

Building the geometry and meshing :

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]

bmesh1 = ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[]];
bmesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[{1/2, 1/2}, 1/4]];
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[bmesh1, bmesh2];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{1/10, 1/10}, 1, 0.001}, {{1/2, 1/2}, 
      2, .001}}];

mesh["Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Lighter@Blue], 
     FaceForm[Lighter@Red]}]]
```

Which gives

[image]

Setting the pde variables and parameters (heat equation):

```
vars = {T[x, y], {x, y}};

pars = <|"HeatSource" -> Q, "MassDensity" -> \[Rho], 
   "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> Cp, "ThermalConductivity" -> k|>;
Q = If[ElementMarker == 1, 1000, 0];
k = If[ElementMarker == 1, 100, 0.1];
\[Rho] = If[ElementMarker == 1 , 10^6, 2 10^6];
Cp = If[ElementMarker == 1, 0.7, 0.2];

pde = {HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 
    DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 300, x == 1]};
Tfun = NDSolveValue[pde, T, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

And displaying the result

```
Show[ContourPlot[Tfun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> 15], bmesh["Wireframe"]]
```

Gives

[image]

Now I can use `Tfun[x,y]` to obtain the mean temperature within the inner disk, such as :

```
NIntegrate[
  Tfun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{1/2, 1/2}, 1/4]]/(Pi (1/4)^2)
(*303.772*)
```

My question is, is it possible to obtain the same result using the ElementMarker that has been assigned to the disk, and to do something like

```
NIntegrate[
      Tfun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh[ElementMarker==2]/(total area of ElementMarker==2)
```

? It would be helpful in cases where the geometry is a bit more complex than this example. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is bad news and good news. The bad news is that it is currently (V13.2) not directly possible to use NIntegrate and mesh element markers. The reason is that NIntegrate (or FEMNIntegrate) make an adaptive mesh refinement, basically from the boundary of the input mesh. During that process the mesh element markers get lost, because currently there is no way to store mesh element marker positions in a boundary mesh. As a side note, the situation is different for boundary integration (e.g., with FEMNBoundaryIntegrate or NIntegrate over a boundary)

Now, the good news, we can work around that. There are probably several ways to do this, but here is one that I kind of had lying around. The idea is that we split the mesh by the marker regions and generate new meshes where each mesh represents the sub region of one marker.

We start with a two helper functions:

```
createSubmesh[coords_, meshEle_] := Module[
  {uniqueIDs, newCoords, map, type, inci, marker},
  uniqueIDs = Union[Flatten[ElementIncidents[meshEle]]];
  newCoords = coords[[uniqueIDs]]; 
  map = Dispatch[Thread[Rule[uniqueIDs, Range[Length[uniqueIDs]]]]];
  type = meshEle[[All, 0]];
  inci = ElementIncidents[meshEle] /. map;
  marker = ElementMarkers[meshEle];
  ElementMesh[newCoords, MapThread[#1[#2, #3] &, {type, inci, marker}]]
  ]

elementMeshSplitByMarker[mesh_] /; 
  ElementMeshQ[mesh] && ! BoundaryElementMeshQ[mesh] := 
 Module[{meshElements, uniqueIDs},
  If[Length[mesh["MeshElementMarkerUnion"]] == 1, 
   Return[{mesh}, Module]];
  meshElements = mesh["MeshElements"];
  meshElements = 
   Flatten[MeshElementSplitByMarker[mesh["MeshElements"]]]; 
  meshElements = 
   Gather[meshElements, 
    Union[ElementMarkers[#1]] == Union[ElementMarkers[#2]] &];
  createSubmesh[mesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ meshElements
  ]
```

Then we can go ahead and do:

```
rr = elementMeshSplitByMarker[mesh];
NIntegrate[Tfun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] rr[[2]]]/
 NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] rr[[2]]]
(*303.772*)
```

One caveat: You will lose boundary and point markers in the new meshes for the edges, points where there might have been some in the original mesh, but I think that bearable.

Hope that helps.